# React Native conditional rendering not working

Tags: react-native, conditional-rendering

I want to have a side menu, with a list of categories and when the user selects a category, it should open a scrollable list, right below the category name, with all the pieces of that category.

So I created two list components, one for the categories (SideMenuList) and one for the furniture pieces. I figured I needed to use conditional rendering to render the second list when the user selects the category.

**My code:**

Side menu code from app.js

```
state = {
  hideMenu: null,
  hideList: null
}

sideMenuShow() {

     if(!this.state.hideMenu) {
        return(
        <SideMenu> 
          <MenuButton onPress = {() => this.setState({hideMenu: true})}/>
          <Text style = {{color: 'white', fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Furniture</Text>
          <SideMenuList onPress = {() => this.setState({hideList: true})}>
            {
              this.state.hideList ? console.log('yes') : null
            }
          </SideMenuList>
        </SideMenu>
        ); 
      }
     else {
         return(
          <SmallSideMenu> 
            <MenuButton onPress = {() => this.setState({hideMenu: false})}/>
          </SmallSideMenu>
         );
     }
 }
```

SideMenuList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { CardSection } from './common';
import SideMenuItem from './SideMenuItem';

class SideMenuList extends Component {

render()  {
    return (
        <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
          <FlatList
            style = {{marginBottom: 2}} 
            data={[
            {key: 'Test'},
            {key: 'Test2'},
            {key: 'Test3'},
            {key: 'Test4'},
            {key: 'Test5'}
            ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
          <TouchableOpacity>
              <SideMenuItem 
              onPress = {this.props.onPress}
              text={item.key}
              >
              {this.props.children}
              </SideMenuItem>
          </TouchableOpacity>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default SideMenuList;
```

SideMenuItem.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const SideMenuItem = (props, {onPress}) => {
return (  
  <View 
  style = {{flex: 1}}>
  <TouchableOpacity
  onPress = {onPress}>
    <Text style={styles.itemStyle}>{props.text}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  {props.children}
  </View>
);
}

const styles = {
  itemStyle: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: 'white' 
   }
};

export default SideMenuItem;
```

My problem right now is that my onPress event is not changing the value of my state property 'hideList', so I can't even check if my solution would actually work. I'm doing a console log when the value is true but it never appears in my console.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering your `SideMenuItem` with a `TouchableOpacity` wrapping it (in your SideMenuList file).

Probably when you are pressing the button, it's triggering SideMenuList button, instead of SideMenuItem button.

Try to remove the `TouchableOpacity` from SideMenuList and check if it works.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that! Makes sense, but I'm still not getting anything from the console.log

Comment: can you try adding a ```console.log(this.props.onPress)``` on both SideMenuLIst and SideMenuItem files?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't answer sooner.

log on both components: 
onPress() {
                  return _this2.setState({
                    hideList: true
                  });
                }

Comment: I figured it out. In the SideMenuItem.js I should only have receive props and then access onPress through props.onPress. Thanks for you help, I got there through the console.log!